# EclipseLink doesn't recognize int(11) in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

I know when I create a table with column data == int. I get something like int(11) as data type for this column. This somehow messes up my EclipseLink when auto generating Entities from Table. Eclipse doesn't understand int(11) as the data type so it converts everything to String instead of int. My question is how to tell MySql to stop showing this (11) thing? Or how to tell EclipseLink that this is a int?

Comment: This is not an EclipseLink problem. This is a Data Tools Platform (DTP) problem. DTP is a plug-in that ships with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. DTP is used by Dali (another Eclipse plug-in) when Dali performs the Entity Generation from Tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out when generating the entity, click on the id and eclipselink will allow you to select the mapping type. Choose int instead of String will do the trick.